# tableColumn setCellFactory

Tags: javafx, tableview, javafx-8, javafx-2

I am new to JavaFX and I built a tableview in JavaFX, and here is the example code:

```
TableView<Person> table = new TableView<>();
table.setEditable(true);
final TableColumn<Person, String>nameCol = new TableColumn<>("Name");
nameCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("name"));
```

After I adding a list into the table, everything works just fine.
But when I add these code after the NameCol:

```
nameCol.setCellFactory(param -> new XCell());

public class XCell extends TableCell<Person, String> {
    @Override
    protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);
        setStyle(empty ? null : "-fx-font-weight: bold; -fx-alignment: center");
//...
    }
}
```

Then, the data from nameColumn went missing.
But when I comment that code:

```
//nameCol.setCellFactory(param -> new XCell());
```

All the data just went back again.
It is so wired that I can't find out what is wrong with that.

I'll appreciate if anyone could explain what is happened and fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you `@Override` the `TableCell`'s `updateItem` method which handles the stuff about what and how is displayed in the cell. If you extending the `TableCell` you have to take care about displaying graphic or text in the cell.

So you should do something like this:

```
public class XCell extends TableCell<TestApp.Person, String> {
    @Override
    protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);
        if(empty){  // check if the cell contains an item or not, if it not you want an empty cell without text.
            setText(null);
        }else {
            setText(item);
            setStyle("-fx-font-weight: bold; -fx-alignment: center"); // You can do the styling here.
            // Any further operations to this cell can be done here in else, since here you have the data displayed.
        }
        // Since as I see you don't have any graphics in the cell(like TextField, ComboBox,...) you 
        // don't have to take care about the graphic, but only the displaying of the text.
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh, yes. I just realized I forgot to setText in each cell. Now it works. Thanks.